unable to fetch spl token metadata using SPL SDK?
My goal is to try to get the metadata for a token. Let's say BONK. The code snippet im using:
  const tokenMetadata = await getTokenMetadata(
    connection,
    new PublicKey("DezXAZ8z7PnrnRJjz3wXBoRgixCa6xjnB7YaB1pPB263"),
    "finalized",
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

Seems to be returning null.
I noticed that the function calls getMint and uses tlvData to determine the metadata. This led me to realizing the tlvData buffer was empty. Is there soemthing that I am doing wrong in this situation? Looks like getMint returns the token with the accurate info. I don't want to just get it form the metaplex SDK just yet if I can get it working using this

BONK only has metaplex metadata, so you'll have to fetch using their SDK
